# Why Markdown wraps text in empty lines?

Tags: python, flask, markdown, jinja2

I use flask and Markdown library to output jinja2-formatted text block on my blog page but I noticed ...|markdown filter adds extra lines around the text posts as empty starting/trailing P tags.
I made sure my webform textarea tag and MongoDB work fine keeping original text "as-is". The problem occurs once markdown filter is applied.
I could use CSS to eliminate extra p tags but it does not look like a good choice. 
Any ideas are appreciated.

UPD: I used texts with and without paragraphs, one-liners etc.

```
This is text with some paragraphs. This is text with some paragraphs. This is text with some paragraphs.

This is text with some paragraphs. This is text with some paragraphs. This is text with some paragraphs. This is text with some paragraphs. This is text with some paragraphs. This is text with some paragraphs. This is text with some paragraphs.
```

UPD: the problem was caused by p tags around markdown output in my jinja2 template, i.e. `<p>{{item.content|markdown}}</p>` made extra pair of p tags to appear like: `<p></p><p>content</p><p></p>`. Now I'm even more puzzled. Is it jinja2 or browser? Is it clear or should I make my question more specific?

Comment: Can you also include the HTML output you are getting? It's not clear to me what the problem is.

Comment: In Markdown, a "paragraph" is a block of text with a blank line between it and the next block of text. You are using the word "paragraphs" in your example when I think you actually mean "sentences".

Answer (score 0):

Look that you don't have any /n or /r/n in you original string. A markdown filter will interpret any line as a paragraph. It mean that you want any paragraph to be on a single line !
Also try to apply you string on another markdown interpreter like https://stackedit.io/ to see if it's a problem related to you input or to your filter.

Comment: I have just checked it. It seems like there is no difference if text block is a one line or it contains paragraphs.

Comment: Can you provide a piece of you markdown in your question so we can understand the problem a bit better ? Thanks !